# replace string and ignore underscore

Tags: c#, regex, string

How to replace string and ignore underscore? the string structure should stay as is. I dont want remove the underscore. just replace the 'world' with 'sharp'. and only for whole words

```
string[] sentences =
{
    "Hello",
    "helloworld",
    "hello_world",
    "hello_world_"
};
foreach (string s in sentences)
{

    string pattern = String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", "world"); // whole case ignore underscore
    string result = Regex.Replace(s, pattern, "charp");

    Console.WriteLine(s + " = " + result);
}
```

output should be:

> // Hello
>
> // helloworld
>
> // hello_charp
>
> // hello_charp_

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: // Hello
// helloworld
// hello_sharp
// hello_scharp_

Comment: if you wnt to remove underscore you can you replace funtion like this s.Replace("_','')

Comment: world should be replace with sharp,

Comment: structure should stay as is. I dont want remove the underscore

Comment: You posted that you want the output like this // Hello

// helloworld

// hello_charp

// hello_charp

after that you mention in a comment that you want it like this
 
// Hello // helloworld // hello_sharp // hello_scharp_
Difference in last word... does it end with"_" or not... that make a big difference
and please be precise next time !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this - in order to *test* for underscopes, but not *include* them into match use *look ahead* and *look behind* regex constructions.

```
  string[] sentences = new string[] {
     "Hello",
     "helloworld",
     "hello_world",
     "hello_world_",
     "hello, my world!", // My special test
     "my-world-to-be",   // ... and another one
     "worlds",           // ... and final one
  };

  String toFind = "world";
  String toReplace = "charp";

  // do to forget to escape (for arbitrary toFind String)
  string pattern = String.Format(@"(\b|(?<=_)){0}(\b|(?=_))", 
    Regex.Escape(toFind)); // whole word ignore underscore

  // Test:

  // Hello
  // helloworld
  // hello_charp
  // hello_charp_
  // hello, my charp!
  // my-charp-to-be
  // worlds

  foreach (String line in sentences)
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(line, pattern, toReplace));
```

In my solution I've assumed that you want to change *whole words* only which are separated by either *word border* (`'\b'`) or underscope `'_'`.

Comment: this doesnt check for whole word

Comment: @user6235593: Sorry, it *does* since word should be wrapped in either `\b` (*word border*) or `_`

Comment: oh btw cant use Linq functions since I use .net2

Comment: @user6235593: I've added a special test to demonstrate that *whole word* is checked

Comment: Thank you, I didn't test your solution propelley. it works just the ways i need it to

Comment: @user6235593: you're welcome, *next time*, please, provide *more tests* (for us not to guess what you're looking for), and specify *restrictions* (i.e. .Net 2.0 and alike)

Answer (score 1):

You should use replace on `_world`

```
string[] sentences =
{
    "Hello",
    "helloworld",
    "hello_world",
    "hello_world_"
};
foreach (string s in sentences)
{

    string pattern = "_world";
    string result = s.Replace(pattern, "_charp");

    Console.WriteLine(s + " = " + result);
}
```

Just in case Dmitry is genuinely correct, it is worth also adding a second replace like so

```
    string pattern1 = "_world";
    string pattern2 = " world";
    string result = s.Replace(pattern1, "_charp").Replace(pattern2, " charp");
```

Comment: Counter example: `"hello world"` should be changed into `"hello charp"`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko where is that stated? The OP never said that and none of their examples have spaces so why should that be necessary to handle?

Comment: technically it's not clearly stated, but in the *question's code* there's attempt to use regular expression `\b{0}\b` which indicates the attempt of *whole word* replacement

Comment: Another counter examples: `"worlds"` should be preserved *intact* when `"my-world-to-be" ` should be *changed* (if you accept the hypothesis of whole word replacement).

Answer (score 0):

using string replace function see this code example

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    const string s = "Dot Net Perls is about Dot Net.";
    Console.WriteLine(s);

    // We must assign the result to a variable.
    // ... Every instance is replaced.
    string v = s.Replace("Net", "Basket");
    Console.WriteLine(v);
    }
}
```

Output

> Dot Net Perls is about Dot Net.
>    Dot Basket Perls is about Dot Basket.

Comment: Counter example: "helloworld" expected to be preserved intact, but "hellocharp" is returned; you can't just `Replace`

Answer (score 0):

in the comments, you specify that "world should be replace with sharp," then   Why not be a simple replace using [`.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string wordToReplace="world";
string replaceWith="charp";
string[] sentences = { "Hello", "helloworld", "hello_world", "hello_world_" };
foreach (string  item in sentences)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Replace(wordToReplace,replaceWith));
}
```

Comment: will it do helloworld to helloSharp ?

Comment: @debin : sorry what you mean

Comment: @un-lucky they are saying that this will turn helloworld into hellosharp, when the OP only wants the word world preceded by an underscore to be changed to sharp

Comment: Counter example: `"helloworld"` expected to be preserved *intact*, but `"hellocharp"` is returned

Comment: Replace function doesnt check of whole word